# How to add values ​from the dom selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use html `()` to get the value of the html attribute then I add 2 values ​​but it's just like adding a string, how can I add the Dom selector to add numbers?

```
var phantram = $('#giamtheophantram').html();
var phantram1 = $('#chuadungma').html();
if(phantram1 == 'contuer'){
  phantram1 = 0;
}
$(document).ready(function() {
document.getElementById('tonggiam').innerHTML = phantram + phantram1;
});
```

Comment: You can use parseInt() and parseFloat() to change string to integer and float and then add it.

Answer (score 1):

`+` append strings (there is no auto retype as in PHP), use `parseInt()` to retype to numbers and make a sum. If decimals are allowed, use `parseFloat()`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById('tonggiam').innerHTML = parseInt(phantram) + parseInt(phantram1);
});
```

Comment: oh thank you, before I thought JS was using var as common, I don't think I can cast it